# Marie command line interpreter

Tags: assembly, command-line, interpreter, marie

Is there anywhere a command-line interpreter for the MARIE assembly?

I realise it is a simple task to implement one, but I am on the process of grading students work and wanted to know if there is a tool that can help me automate this procedure.

I have come across a number of simulators, html based and (such as https://github.com/MARIE-js ), but I wanted something simpler that could read a write files from a script.

I was going to write this myself, as I could not find one, but as the web is big, I was wondering if someone knew about one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wrote the thing myself.

If anyone else ever wants to use it:

https://github.com/mysablehats/marie-sim

Comment: @WaiHaLee: The problem isn't this answer, it's the question.  The only possible answer to a software-recommendation question is a URL, so I don't think the downvote is appropriate.  The question is simply off topic, but neither it nor the answer need to be downvoted.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Right, IDK why I assumed you were the downvoter as well as commenter.  I think I meant to say that flagging this as not-an-answer or as a link-only answer isn't correct either, because it's the only answer possible unless the entire source fits in an SO answer.  Or maybe a tutorial on using it?  IDK.  Still, seems like a good answer to me.  @ user27...: thanks for sharing your work.  I'll add a link to your github in the `[tag:marie]` tag wiki.